# parseInt vs isDigit

Tags: java, parseint

I need my code to return true if the parameter is the String representation of an integer between 0 and 255 (including 0 and 255), false otherwise.

For example:
Strings "0", "1", "2" .... "254", "255" are valid.

Padded Strings (such as "00000000153") are also valid.

isDigit apparently would also work but i was wondering if this would be more beneficial and/or this would even work with Padded Strings?

```
public static boolean isValidElement(String token) {
    int foo = Integer.parseInt("token");
    if(foo >= 0 && foo <= 255)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Your code is not working ?

Comment: JavaScript and Java are two completely different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isDigit` would not work, because it takes a character as input, and returns true if it is a digit from 0 to 9. [Reference : [isDigit javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char))]

Since in your case you need to test string representations of all numbers from 0 to 255 hence you must use [`parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).

Additionally also check if the token passed is a valid number by catching `NumberFormatException` and returning false in case it is not a valid integer.

```
public static boolean isValidElement(String token) {
    try{
        int foo = Integer.parseInt(token);
        if(foo >= 0 && foo <= 255)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the catch and ex mean in "catch (NumberFormatException ex)" ? and why do you open with try ?

Comment: `try` and `catch` are Java keywords. `parseInt` will throw `NumberFormatException ` if it is supplied with input that cannot be parsed as an integer (for example `Integer.parseInt("randomText")`). `try-catch` is a syntax to catch that exception and do the correct thing, i.e., return `false` since input is not valid element (not representation of number between 0 to 255). You can read more about `try-catch` in [java official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex:

```
return token.matches("1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]");
```

Answer (score 0):

So Integer.parseInt will throw a NumberFormatException if the string is not a valid number, just something to keep in mind.

I would use NumberUtils.isDigit() from commons-math3 library to check, then use Integer.valueOf which is an efficient number parser.

```
if (NumberUtils.isDigit(token)) {
    int foo = Integer.valueOf(token);
    return (foo >=0 && foo <=255);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Integer.parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) throws a [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) if the conversion is not possible. Having that in mind you can use this code snippet. *No additional dependencies are needed.*

```
public static boolean isValidElement(String token) {
    try {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(token);
        return value >= 0 && value <= 255;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```